# Add default program for opening txt files

Tags: windows-7

I'm working on a `Windows 7` machine without adimn rights. Since I love `Notepad ++` as an text editor I downloaded the portable version. So far so good.
Now I want to tell `windows` to use `Notepad ++` as standard for opening txt files.
Normally I would right-click on a txt file, choose `open with` and then go to something like default program, navigate to the `exe` of NP++ and that's it.
However, after I selected the `exe` `Notepad ++` does not show up in the list of programs.

[image: Menu of programs]

How can I add a default program so I can open a txt file with `notepad ++`? Maybe using the registry (if thats possible without admin rights)?

Comment: Did u select the option **Always use this to open txt files** when u have selected notepad++ ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see NP++ in the list of files after I selected it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue once for some users in our company.
I found out that sometimes it messes up a registry key when you work with 64bit Notepad++ after working with 32bit Notepad++ and vice versa.

However I found the solution for this issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/problems-with-file-association-in-windows-7-64-bit/8a84fcec-22df-4942-8e35-d98dbe96e327)
and created a `fix_notepad.reg` file containing the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe\shell\open\command]   
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

It fixes the issue if you have installed the 64bit version now.

**For your case:**
Check the specified registry key and correct the path to your Notepad++ exe.
After that, it should be available in Open-with dialog again and you can set it as default.

Comment: I nearly solved my problem. I realized that I changed the path of the protable installation and in the registry, the old path was still there. Changing this worked!
Thank you!

Comment: Here is the commands:: `ftype NotepadPlus="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1" && assoc .txt=NotepadPlus`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the default list is based on which programs accessed files with the respective extension through a common file dialog. So opening/saving a file might be enough.

As an alternative, try associating for extensions through Notepad++'s options. This should make it appear under "Default Programs".

The quickest way is to just click the Browse button in the screenshot and find Notepad++'s executable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
The way you describe clocking the browse button is what I tried. I get the same picture before and after I selected the NP++.exe.
I treid to associate the extention in Notepadd++'s options, but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Select on any of the file you will want to open with Notepad++, that is, the files with `.txt` extension, then you right-click on the `.txt` file, choose **open with** and then you select **choose default program...**, you should have this window coming up [image: Open with]

If you don't have notepad++ shown among your Recommended Programs and other Programs, click on the select the **Browse** button, but ensure you check the **Always use the selected program to open this kind of file**.

If you have you notepad++ install normally, the moment you click on the browser button, a window should pop up for you, there you should navigate to your **C:** drive => **Program Files (x86) => **Notepad++** => **Notepad** as shown in the image below

[image: notepad]

After which you click on open.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is exactly the way I'm used to go. However, if I click on "browse", select notepad++.exe it dows not show up in the "open with" window. In other words, before I slect nopepad++.exe and afterwards, the list of programs is exactly the same.
BTW: Since I don't have admin rights, I cannot install notepad++. So I use a portable version, which, in general, works fine.